# How to configure IntelliJ IDEA and/or Maven to automatically add directories with Java source code generated using jaxb2-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven-2, jaxb, intellij-idea

In our project we are using `jaxb2-maven-plugin` to generate Java source code from XML Schema, which causes that our Maven module requires additional source code directory (in our case `target/generated/main/java`). Up to date I've been using Eclipse and `maven-eclipse-plugin` to import all the projects into Eclipse workspace. The plugin is (somehow) able to add the directory with generated source code automatically to Eclipse' .classpath file.

Recently I try to switch to (play with?) IntelliJ IDEA 9 (so I am a newbie in this environment) and I've noticed that additional source directory is not added during IDEA's importing process...

Is there any way I can configure IDEA/Maven to make importing directory with generated source code automatically?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The convention with Maven is to generate code in `target/generated-sources/<tool>`, for example `target/generated-sources/jaxb2`

Follow this convention and IDEA will add the folder as source folder (see [IDEA-53198](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-53198)).

Comment: But what if we need to set custom value? What if the directory is used also with another tool doing another phase?
At this time, with Eclipse we don't have a problem, but with IDEA we do.

Comment: @dmatej It is possible to set the location for generated sources. See 'Generated sources folders' option at http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/maven-importing.html

Comment: Be sure to use mvn idea:idea to ensure that this takes place after adding the mvn plugin module to your pom.

Comment: `mvn idea:idea` solved the issue in my case. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Generated code, using jaxb2-maven-plugin, was missing for me in Intellij 2017.1 whereas Eclipse Neon created it.
Fixed it from context menu of module by selecting 'Maven -> Generate Sources and Update Folders'.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin). If it does not work then it's IDEA problem.

In Maven you can add new source roots per configuration. Maven plugins can do this programmatically. This is for sure the case with `maven-jaxb2-plugin`. Then, if IDEA does not recognize it, then it's a problem on that side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Maven Build Helper Plugin. It is located at http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/

It allows to configure additional source roots. And the maven integration of IntelliJ will add the new source root. We are using this feature in quite a few builds and it works just fine. Tested with vers. 13 of IntelliJ IDEA.