# How to consume Amazon SWF

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

[Amazon SWF](http://aws.amazon.com/swf/) was launched today.  How best to consume it with Java / PHP / etc. ?

The current SDK support doesn't appear to include it.  I know it's new, but does anyone have any good resources on how to consume it, or what changes I'd need to implement in the any of the following SDK's to get going right away?

- [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/)
- [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/php/)
- [AWS SDK for Python](http://aws.amazon.com/python/)
- [AWS SDK for Ruby](http://aws.amazon.com/ruby/)
- [AWS SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/net/)

Personally, my interest is on the Java & PHP SDK's...

Updated releases are visible at:  http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes  Thanks Bjorn!

Comment: If you want to do this with Gradle, check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550393/gradle-1-0-spring-aspectj-build-problems/41755384#41755384

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I'm using Amazon Simple Workflow Service (SWF) to implement asynchronous business processing using the AWS Flow Framework.  It was important to me to have my development build setup using Maven, so that I could easily build from my IDE of choice (IntelliJ IDEA) as well as automate my test builds for continuous integration and production builds for release and deploy.

Most of my time was spent trying to get the auto-generated proxy classes created using AspectJ.  This was initially a problem for me in Eclipse as I was using version 3.7 (Indigo) and even after following both the load-time and compile-time weaving instructions in the [Setting up the Development Environment](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/setup.html) documentation I was unable to successfully get the classes blown out.  On a hunch I remembered that the documentation says they used Eclipse 3.6 (Helios), so I downloaded this specific version of Eclipse and retried using the load-time weaving approach and it worked like a champ.  Looking at the Eclipse logs between these two versions I was able to see that Eclipse 3.7 is missing a dependency for `log4j` and `freemarker`.  I didn't bother going too far down the road to troubleshoot this further with Eclipse as I'm more of an IntelliJ IDEA user, but I'm sure that it's most definitely possible to get Eclipse working properly.

My next effort was to get an IntelliJ IDEA Maven project up and running with the minimum amount of information in my `pom.xml` to enable the auto-generation of the proxy classes.  The clue was the last paragraph of the instructions for load-time weaving in the Setting up the Development Environment documentation, which states:

> If you are building your project from the command line, ensure that
>   aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools-1.3.3.jar is in the classpath. This jar
>   file contains the AWS Flow Framework annotation processor that must be
>   run to generate code. For an example, see the build.xml file included
>   in the samples folder.

Unless I'm mistaken, the research I've done to date indicates that the `aspectj-maven-plugin` doesn't not currently support load-time weaving.  Breaking away from doing load-time weaving and utilizing an `aop.xml` file in conjunction with `aspectjweaver` running as a Java agent, I moved to compile-time weaving supported by this plugin.  I can't help but think that when I installed the AWS SDK for Java support directly in Eclipse that it in turn baked in the support found in the `aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools-1.3.3.jar` dependency.  Taking the aforementioned clue, I was finally able to get the proxy classes blowing out by including a dependency for `aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools-1.3.3.jar` in my `pom.xml` after installing this JAR into my local Maven repository.  The rest of this entry outlines the steps taken to make this all happen.

### IntelliJ IDEA Project Creation

1. Start the **IntelliJ IDEA** application.
2. Create a **New Project**.
3. Input the **Project name** and **Project files location**.
4. Select type should be **Maven Module**.
5. Adjust any Maven properties if appropriate on next screen and click **Finish**.
6. Follow the **Maven** instructions below for setting up the `pom.xml`.

### AWS SDK for Java

In order to reference the necessary types for developing workflows and activities, you will need to download the AWS SDK for Java. It is recommended that you use **Maven** to include a `dependency` for this library for your project and build, but you should still download this library in order to get the `aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools` library which can be found under the `lib` directory.

### SWF Flow Build Tools

The **AWS SDK for Java** download includes a `aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools-<version>.jar` JAR under the `lib` directory.  In order to allow the inclusion of a Maven `dependency` for this library, you'll need to install the JAR into your local **Maven** repository.  You can achieve this by running the following from the `lib` directory of the AWS SDK download:

```
mvn install:install-file 
    -Dfile=aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools-<version>.jar 
    -DgroupId=com.amazonaws 
    -DartifactId=aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools 
    -Dversion=<version> 
    -Dpackaging=jar
```

***NOTE:** Be sure to replace the  tokens in the above command with the appropriate version found in your AWS SDK download.*

### Maven

Your `pom.xml` file should include the following `dependencies`.  I've included the version numbers I'm using in case you run into breaking changes using different versions:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.18</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Your `pom.xml` file should also include the following `plugin`.  I'm using source include patterns that following a packaging and interface naming convention I use in my code, though you don't necessarily need to do things this way:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <complianceLevel>1.5</complianceLevel>
        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <sources>
            <source>
                <basedir>src/main/java</basedir>
                <includes>
                    <include>*/**/workflow/*Workflow.java</include>
                    <include>*/**/workflow/activities/*Activities.java</include>
                </includes>
            </source>
        </sources>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Once you've include the `plugin` listed above and have at least run a Maven `compile`, you should notice an `aspectj` node appear under the `Plugins` node within the **Maven Projects** tool window in IntelliJ IDEA.  You can also optional add or tweak the elements of the `configuration` section of the `aspectj-maven-plugin` plugin if you desire.  The various supported settings can be found in the `aspectj:compile` goal documentation found [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html).  I've haven't tweaked my plugin configuration yet to ensure that the `.java` files are generated in the proper location under my source directory, though I'm sure this is quite doable.

### External Libraries

Once you've include the set of `dependencies` listed above and have at least run a Maven `compile`, you should notice at minimum the following set of dependencies listed under the **External Libraries** node within the **Project** tool window in IntelliJ IDEA:

- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools
- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk
- commons-codec:commons-codec
- commons-logging:commons-logging
- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient
- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore
- org.aspectj:aspectjrt
- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl
- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl
- org.freemarker:freemarker

### Example pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>swf_example</groupId>
    <artifactId>swf_example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.18</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>1.5</complianceLevel>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <sources>
                        <source>
                            <basedir>src/main/java</basedir>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*/**/workflow/*Workflow.java</include>
                                <include>*/**/workflow/activities/*Activities.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### Defining Workflows

To define a workflow you must create a Java interface that meets the following criteria:

1. The interface is annotated with **@Workflow**.
2. A single method is defined for the interface that is annotated with **@Execute** and has a **version** property set.
3. The interface has a name that ends with the string **Workflow**.
4. The interface resides under a package that ends with **workflow**.

The following is an example workflow interface named `MyWorkflow`, and would be contained a file named `MyWorkflow.java`, located under the source directory `src/main/java`, and under the package directory structure `com/some/package/workflow`.  I haven't included the `@WorkflowRegistrationOptions` annotation or other bells and whistles as these aren't required and are dependent on your particular needs:

```
package com.some.package.workflow;

import com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.annotations.Execute;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.annotations.Workflow;

@Workflow
public interface MyWorkflow {

    @Execute(version="1.0")
    void doWorkflow();

}
```

### Defining Activities

To define activities you must create a Java interface that meets the following criteria:

1. The interface is annotated with **@Activities** and has a **version** property set.
2. The interface has a name that ends with the string **Activities**.
3. The interface resides under a package that ends with **workflow/activities**.

The following is an example activities interface named `MyActivities`, and would be contained in a file named `MyActivities.java`, located under the source directory `src/main/java`, and under the package directory structure `com/some/package/workflow/activities`.  I haven't included the `@ActivityRegistrationOptions` annotation or other bells and whistles as these aren't required and are dependent on your particular needs:

```
package com.some.package.workflow.activities;

import com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.annotations.Activities;

@Activities(version="1.0")
public interface MyActivities {

    void doActivity1();
    void doActivity2();
    void doActivity3();

}
```

### Building

In order to ensure that the build process is the same during everyday development as well as for non-development environments (e.g. test, production, etc.), you should run builds in your development tool of choice through **Maven**.  Various aspects have been included in the `aws-java-sdk` and `aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools` JARs which are weaved into your workflows and activities, and the `aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools` JAR includes the necessary mechanism to auto-generate the required proxy classes to execute workflows and activities.  In order to ensure that you're working with the latest generated proxy classes, you should take care to clean the generated artifacts before a build in order to throw away unneeded and/or old classes.  This can be achieved by running the following command or equivalent in your development tool of choice:

```
mvn clean install
```

If you keep the `showWeaveInfo` configuration option enabled in the `aspectj-maven-plugin` plugin, you should see something like the following snippet in your build output, albeit there are only have a few lines of output here due to only having a single workflow and single activities for this run:

```
Mar 12, 2012 5:21:22 PM com.amazonaws.eclipse.simpleworkflow.asynchrony.annotationprocessor.AsynchronyDeciderAnnotationProcessor process
INFO: AsynchronyDeciderAnnotationProcessor.process() invoked.
Mar 12, 2012 5:21:22 PM com.amazonaws.eclipse.simpleworkflow.asynchrony.annotationprocessor.AsynchronyDeciderAnnotationProcessor process
INFO: Processing @Activities for MyActivities
Mar 12, 2012 5:21:22 PM com.amazonaws.eclipse.simpleworkflow.asynchrony.annotationprocessor.AsynchronyDeciderAnnotationProcessor process
INFO: Processing @Workflow for MyWorkflow
Mar 12, 2012 5:21:22 PM com.amazonaws.eclipse.simpleworkflow.asynchrony.annotationprocessor.AsynchronyDeciderAnnotationProcessor process
INFO: AsynchronyDeciderAnnotationProcessor.process() invoked.
```

### Auto-Generated Proxies

Once you've compiled your workflows and activities you should find the follow set of auto-generated proxy classes have been created.  These proxies are to be used within your workflows to call upon your various activities, execute child workflows within other workflows, and also to execute workflows at a top level.  ***NOTE:** The strings "Workflow" and "Activities" in the following bullets would actually be the name of your actual workflow and activities interfaces respectively, and you should see the following set of classes created for each of your defined workflow and activities interfaces:*

- Workflow**Client.java**
- Workflow**ClientExternal.java**
- Workflow**ClientExternalFactory.java**
- Workflow**ClientExternalFactoryImpl.java**
- Workflow**ClientExternalImpl.java**
- Workflow**ClientFactory.java**
- Workflow**ClientFactoryImpl.java**
- Workflow**ClientImpl.java**
- Workflow**SelfClient.java**
- Workflow**SelfClientImpl$1.java**
- Workflow**SelfClientImpl.java**
- Activities**Client.java**
- Activities**ClientImpl.java**

I'm also including some background information to help clarify the type of development environment I'm working on and tools I'm using for day to day coding.

**OS**

```
Mac OS X version 10.7.3
```

**Java**

```
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11-402-11D50b)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02-402, mixed mode)
```

**Maven**

```
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 12:31:09-0500)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_29, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.7.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

**IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition)**

```
IntelliJ IDEA 11.0.2
Build #IC111.277
Built on February 1, 2012
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this thing many more times.  Incredibly useful and helpful.  Thank you for your detailed response!

Comment: Shouldn't the "aspectj-maven-plugin" configuration include "aws-java-sdk" as an aspectLibrary if you want to use AWS aspects on your activities (such as the @ExponentialRetry annotation and its associated aspect ExponentialRetryAspect)

Comment: @GuiSim - yes, I had to include it to make exponential retry work: `<aspectLibraries>
  <aspectLibrary>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
  </aspectLibrary>
</aspectLibraries>`
I also had to include the directory where it puts my generated source in the sources block. `<source>
  <basedir>target</basedir>
  <includes>
     <include>**/*.java</include>
  </includes>
</source>`

Comment: For those who stumble here in the future: If intellij is not able to resolve symbols, you can see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170620/unable-to-use-intellij-with-a-generated-sources-folder).

Comment: @KenjiMatsuoka could you post your pom.xml or could you elaborate on the steps to making asynchronous and exponential retry annotation work.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more recent answer that works for Java8 (JDK8) and compile time weaving.

The problem is that the maven compiler can perform annotation processing. If its turned on and aspectj, you will try to double create the same classes.
its better to leave the maven compiler to process the annotations (generate the workflow/activity classes) since aspectJ needs them created so it can then do its weaving (@Retry @Async)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>       <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>  <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
          <!-- This is important so we don't double process the annotations -->
                <proc>none</proc>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Did you check the updated SDKs today? There was a new release about 10 hours ago (1.4.3 for .NET at least, released on February 21, 2012).

http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/.NET/5023081835314406

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes <-- nice!

Answer (score 3):

Several years later, this thread helped me a lot to make AWS SWF Flow work with Maven. However, some aspects are not working out of the box with this approach. I have written [an article](http://www.ana-todor.ro/using-the-aws-flow-java-framework-with-intellij-idea-and-maven/26/02/2015/) to concentrate all my findings. PS: would love some tips to make Java 1.8 work as well with this.

Answer (score 3):

For the brave souls that read this:
Most of the stuff still applies. To make it work with Java 1.8, you need to use the following aspect library with AspectJ:

```
<aspectLibraries>
  <aspectLibrary>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries</artifactId>
  </aspectLibrary>
</aspectLibraries>
```

For a full sample look at:
https://github.com/mirceal/swf-flow-java18-sample

Comment: Thanks for sharing Mircea. I tried your solution and it helped me up the version of the AWS SDK from 1.7.3 to 1.9.23. However, aspects are still not detected and weaved properly in Java 1.8. You can see my pom.xml in the article I shared (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15628688/pom.xml).

Comment: hmm... it's definitely working for me. Will try to put together a sample pom these days.

Comment: No rush, I can work with 1.7 for now. But would be great for Internet posterity :).

Comment: Thanks, I will try it when I get the chance.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  That GitHub repo included in the answer has everything you need.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to make JAVA8 / AWS SDK 1.9.x work with Maven and Eclipse following this remarkable examples [pedropaulovc/aws-flow-maven-eclipse-samples](https://github.com/pedropaulovc/aws-flow-maven-eclipse-samples) and tweaking the pom.xml, including the brave Mircea suggestion and other reworks.

you can find the resulting working pom.xml [here](https://gist.github.com/robizz/25fa13a7959cd9b354ba)

Note that i had to add to the aspectj plugin aspect libraries also the updated flow-build-tools, otherwise, the Activity and Workflow impl version number annotations do not work properly

```
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <!-- for aspect weaving and swf versions -->
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
```

Hope this could be helpful!