# AspectJ AJC working with aspectj-maven-plugin but not Gradle

Tags: spring, maven, aspectj, gradle

I have been trying to get spring-aspects copiled into a Gradle application.

I first was trying to get a Vaadin Spring integration working and have copied vaadin-6-spring-3-integration-2/][1](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Spring%20Integration) and [Vaadin Spring Integration](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Spring%20Integration) and when I run the application from Gradle with the exact task from https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-aspects/aspects.gradle nothing gets Autowired (everything is null). I have also tried this version: 'https://raw.github.com/breskeby/gradleplugins/0.9-upgrade/aspectjPlugin/aspectJ.gradle'
I also used the updated version noted on [gradle-1-0-spring-aspectj-build-problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550393/gradle-1-0-spring-aspectj-build-problems) but nothing seems to work with spring-aspects compile time weaving except for the Maven plugin.
Here is the Gradle task I have used last:

```
task compileJava(dependsOn: JavaPlugin.PROCESS_RESOURCES_TASK_NAME, overwrite: true)  {
    dependsOn configurations.ajc.getTaskDependencyFromProjectDependency(true, "compileJava")

    doLast{
        ant.taskdef( resource:"org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties", classpath: configurations.ajc.asPath)
        ant.iajc(source:sourceCompatibility, target:targetCompatibility, destDir:sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.absolutePath, maxmem:"512m", fork:"true",
                aspectPath:configurations.aspects.asPath, inpath:configurations.ajInpath.asPath, sourceRootCopyFilter:"**/.svn/*,**/*.java",classpath:configurations.compile.asPath){
            sourceroots{
                sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each{
                    pathelement(location:it.absolutePath)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then when I created a Maven pom to use the following plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Required as the plugin does not resolve this by default -->
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The application is autowired fine.

Can anyone help getting Gradle to work?

Comment: Have you managed to get aspectj working with gradle? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is your code somewhere available? I don't think its a problem of the aspectj task itself.