# How to configure Maven to compile current AWS SWF code

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, aspectj-maven-plugin

For a good recent version of AWS SDK such as 1.11.28, what do I put in my pom.xml so that Maven can weave and compile everything?  This topic is discussed in several places, but all answers I can find are YEARS OLD and I can only get them to work for ancient versions of the AWS SDK, if at all.

[How to consume Amazon SWF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392655/how-to-consume-amazon-swf)
<-- This has a solid answer for AWS 1.3.3, and one of the answers hints at 1.9.x, but that is still years old.

http://www.ana-todor.ro/using-the-aws-flow-java-framework-with-intellij-idea-and-maven/ <-- This works like a charm, but only for AWS 1.7 and old versions of AspectJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much googling, reading, pondering, trial-and-error, and gnashing of teeth, I now have a POM that successfully compiles SWF-based applications for AWS SDK version 1.11.35 (I use this with Java 1.7, by the way).  It wasn't as much about getting the version numbers just right, but it was more about getting exactly the right names of the components (apparently Amazon has changed the way their SDK is organized more than once in recent years).  So here it is:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>groupid</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproj</artifactId>
  <version>1.01</version>
  <name>MyProjName</name>

  <properties>
    <target.dir>target</target.dir>
    <annotations.dir>${target.dir}/generated-sources/annotations</annotations.dir>
    <aws.version>1.11.35</aws.version>
    <flow.tools.name>aws-swf-build-tools</flow.tools.name>
    <flow.tools.version>1.0</flow.tools.version>
    <freemarker.version>2.3.25-incubating</freemarker.version>
    <aspectj-runtime.version>1.7.4</aspectj-runtime.version>
    <aspectj-maven-plugin.version>1.8</aspectj-maven-plugin.version>
    <compliance.level>1.7</compliance.level>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- dependencies for AWS Flow -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>${aws.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>${flow.tools.name}</artifactId>
      <version>${flow.tools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
      <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependencies for preprocessing SWF's @annotations: -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
      <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
      <version>${freemarker.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>${aspectj-runtime.version}</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>

      <!-- Use a standalone annotation processor -->
      <plugin>
    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>process</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${annotations.dir}</outputDirectory>
          <processor>
              com.amazonaws.eclipse.simpleworkflow.asynchrony.annotationprocessor.AsynchronyDeciderAnnotationProcessor
          </processor>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>${flow.tools.name}</artifactId> 
            <version>${flow.tools.version}</version>
          </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${aws.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>${freemarker.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Tell Maven NOT to do any annotation processing: -->
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
      <compilerArguments>
        <Xmaxerrs>5</Xmaxerrs>
      </compilerArguments>          
      <source>${compliance.level}</source>
      <target>${compliance.level}</target>
    </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Enable weaving via AspectJ: -->
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${aspectj-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- Include this in order to keep aspectjrt consistent across all dependencies: -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj-runtime.version}</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
      <complianceLevel>${compliance.level}</complianceLevel>
      <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
      <verbose>true</verbose>
      <source>${compliance.level}</source>
      <target>${compliance.level}</target>
      <aspectLibraries>
        <aspectLibrary>
          <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
          <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        </aspectLibrary>
            <aspectLibrary>
              <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
          <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries</artifactId>
            </aspectLibrary>
      </aspectLibraries>
      <sources>
        <source>
          <basedir>${annotations.dir}</basedir>
        </source>
        <source>
          <basedir>src/main/java</basedir>
        </source>
      </sources>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal> <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
          <goal>test-compile</goal> <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```