# define additional source directory in maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, code-generation

I generate Java sources from a wsdl file. These sources are not under version control (but the wsdl is). We use the cxf-codegen-plugin in maven and the generated classes are generated in `<sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>`.

This works all fine in maven.

I have to define this directory as addition source directory in Intelij Idea. (`target`is normaly excluded).

But every time I re-import the maven project into InteliJ Idea (due to pom changes), I have to manually edit the project structure in Idea and redefine the addition source directory.

Is there any way I can either define this aditional source directory in maven, so Idea picks it up on reload, or tell Idea not to forget the manual source directoy definition?

Comment: Did you check http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Maven_FAQ ?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Should have checked their wiki first. "generated-sources" did the trick. Thanks. Can you post it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This case is described in the [IntelliJ IDEA Maven FAQ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/maven-importing.html), **Generated Sources** section:

> Specify the directory of your source root when you reimport a project.
>   You can select one of the following options:
>
> - Detect automatically This is a default option. When you select this option, IntelliJ IDEA automatically detects the location of the generated sources. IntelliJ IDEA also detects which directory to mark as a source root. However, IntelliJ IDEA searches for the generated sources only in target/generated-sources and target/generated-sources/* directories.
> - target/generated-sources This option enables you to mark the directory as source root manually.
> - subdirectories of "target/generated-sources" This option enables you to mark a subdirectory as a source root manually.
> - Don't detect This option lets you skip the detection process.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the `<add-source>` build goal (see an example [here](http://blog.tfd.co.uk/2009/07/29/howto-add-more-than-one-source-directory-into-a-maven-build/))

Quote:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.4</version>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <id>add-wsdl-source</id>
   <phase>generate-sources</phase>
   <goals>
    <goal>add-source</goal>
   </goals>
   <configuration>
    <sources>
     <source>${basedir}/src-generated/src</source>
    </sources>
   </configuration>
   <!-- [...] -->
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: this does generate the sources outside of the target folder and I can build the project. Unfortunately, Idea still need manual definition of this additional folder, hence my problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

You could define the (external) source directory as an dependency to your module. `Project Structure -> Modules -> Depenencies`. There you have to add a new `JAR or Directory` dependency.

Comment: thanks. Idea does keep this change after pom reload. Java files are recognized as such. Unfortunately, Idea does not resolve class references to files in such a directory. Strange, I will investigate furter