# How to add more source directory with maven and make eclipse/intellij idea realize the source directory?

Tags: maven

I've tried build-helper-maven-plugin, but it only take effects during compilation through maven commands, ide can't recognize the source directory set by the plugin.

Comment: In eclipse you can just right click on your source directory and choose `Build Path > Use as Source Folder` to make it recognize the new source directory.

Comment: Eclipse should recognize the `sourceDirectory` tag in the `build` section of your pom.xml, if you update the project configuration. Is the maven nature enabled in eclipse?

Comment: Possible duplicate. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735380/define-additional-sorce-directory-in-maven

Comment: In my case to resolve generated sources (added by `build-helper-maven-plugin`) by Eclipse i had to call: `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse`