# new to soap - web service link does not work

Tags: java, soap, soapui

This link is suppose to give you a stock quote:

http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?op=GetQuote

However, when you click the invoke button, I get the following error:

> System.IO.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.FileStream.WriteCore(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
>   System.IO.FileStream.FlushWrite(Boolean calledFromFinalizer)    at
>   System.IO.FileStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)    at
>   System.IO.Stream.Close()    at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean
>   disposing)    at System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose()    at
>   Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters
>   options, String[] sources)    at
>   Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters
>   options, String[] sources)    at
>   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParameters
>   options, String[] sources)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns,
>   XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
>   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[]
>   xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence,
>   XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly,
>   Hashtable assemblies)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings,
>   Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence
>   evidence)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.FromMappings(XmlMapping[]
>   mappings, Type type)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.XmlReturn.GetInitializers(LogicalMethodInfo[]
>   methodInfos)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.XmlReturnWriter.GetInitializers(LogicalMethodInfo[]
>   methodInfos)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.MimeFormatter.GetInitializers(Type type,
>   LogicalMethodInfo[] methodInfos)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerType..ctor(Type type)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type,
>   HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response,
>   Boolean& abortProcessing)

I tried this on 2 different computers and 2 different locations, yet I get the same error 
I even tried other web service examples on that page, and all the web services give the same error.

Comment: Its disk space on the server not the client PC

Comment: Contact the service provider

Comment: no that doesnt make sense. .. because ALL of the web services on that link are giving the same error

Answer (score 0):

The server in question is out of disk space.

If you just want a generic SOAP service for testing, try this WSDL instead - http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL

Comment: thanks, I can do a wsimport to get the files needed in eclipse, but how do I find the java code to call this ? plz keep in mind that I am new to soap

Comment: This thread seems excellent - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940234/how-to-do-a-soap-web-service-call-from-java-class