# Java,How to send SOAPRequset from a xml file?

Tags: soap

I am starting with web service and i dont know how to send a xml file (read from local) with SOAP to send to Web Service by Java code. 
Please help, Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think that first of all it will be good for you to read some example of SOAP usage (I think that you already did it, But just in case, bring a couple of sources on which I've studied):

- Good article about ["How to write oldscool SOAP"](https://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=STY_XML_21days&seqNum=228).
- Article about ["How to write clean SOAP"](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075167/soa/clean-up-your-wire-protocol-with-soap--part-1.html).
- Also there is one more good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940234/how-to-do-a-soap-web-service-call-from-java-class/15942217#15942217) of calling SOAP from Java
  class.

Hope that it will help.