# Consuming SOAP WebService with Java issue

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I was reading a lot of tutorials and similar questions on stackoverflow, but I still have a problem connecting to my SOAP service.

I am trying to call a SOAP web service using Java. I found a nice answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15942217/2145530

The example works perfectly as is but when I change it to another wsdl file it no longer works:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    // Create SOAP Connection
    SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

    // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
    String url = "http://192.168.200.165/soap/server.php";
    SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

    // print SOAP Response
    System.out.print("Response SOAP Message:");
    soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);

    soapConnection.close();
}

private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    String serverURI = "urn:BoardSOAP";

    // SOAP Envelope
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("soap", serverURI);

    System.out.println(envelope.getNamespaceURI());

    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI  + "getBoardStatus");

    soapMessage.saveChanges();

    /* Print the request message */
    System.out.print("Request SOAP Message:");
    soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
    System.out.println();

    return soapMessage;
}
```

As you can see I changed those lines:

```
String url = "http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx";
String serverURI = "http://ws.cdyne.com/";
headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI  + "ReturnCodes");

String url = "http://192.168.200.165/soap/server.php";
String serverURI = "urn:BoardSOAP";
headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI  + "getBoardStatus");
```

Here is my wsdl file: [image: wsdl]

Full output:

```
    http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
Request SOAP Message:<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="urn:BoardSOAP"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body/></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
Response SOAP Message:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode xsi:type="xsd:string">SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode><faultactor xsi:type="xsd:string"></faultactor><faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">Operation &apos;&apos; is not defined in the WSDL for this service</faultstring><detail xsi:type="xsd:string"></detail></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

WSDL file isn't corrupted, I can communicate with it via SoupUI with no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the answer you cite, the `soapAction` for `ReturnCodes` is `http://ws.cdyne.com/ReturnCodes`, which is constructed by the line `headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI  + "ReturnCodes");`

However, in your WSDL, since you are using not a URL but a URN for your namespace identifier, the `soapAction` for `getBoardStatus` is `urn:server#getBoardStatus`. If you use the same concatenation scheme, you will be missing the `#` **and** you will be using `urn:BoardSoap` instead of `urn:server`.

Try using `headers.Header("SOAPAction", "urn:server#getBoardStatus").

Answer (score -1):

This way also worked for me:

```
saajSoapMessage.setSoapAction("urn:server#getBoardStatus");
```