# calling soap web service with https from java

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am trying to call a SOAP webservice from java, these are third part web services which can be http or https
For me this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/15942217/2145530 works fine.
But I need to call https webservice also which is throwing me exception.

Plase Help

```
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection post
SEVERE: SAAJ0009: Message send failed
Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(Unknown Source)
at com.adnate.wsdlparse.WsdlParse.main(WsdlParse.java:23)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(Unknown Source)
... 2 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
... 16 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
... 22 more
CAUSE:
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(Unknown Source)
at com.adnate.wsdlparse.WsdlParse.main(WsdlParse.java:23)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
... 16 more
```

Comment: would be helpful if you posted the error

Comment: Did you verify that the SSL certificate for the soap service is trusted?

Comment: @robjwilkins i just added the error i am getting

Comment: @semvdwal ssl certificate is self signed and thats why it is giving me error 
Is there a way i can somehow send request to server

Comment: To read the content of url I used TrustManager class and X509Certificate but in this case i am not able to send request to server as certificate is not trusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at this article:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/unable-to-connect-to-ssl-services-due-to-pkix-path-building-failed-779355358.html

suggests there is a problem either with the cert, or the truststore.  If its self-signed you need to generate a truststore and tell your process to use that when calling the service

Answer (score 0):

Please note that trusting all certificates is not recommended. Don't do this, unless you really know what you're doing.

Depending on your requirements, u might need to disable both Certificate Validation and Hostname validation by setting setDefaultHostnameVerifier as well.

Use at own risk, not recommended to disable SSL checks and might affect the whole JVM.

```
// Set HTTPS/SSL Trust All Certs and Hosts Params
final boolean isHttps = soapEndPointUri.toLowerCase().startsWith("https");
if (isHttps) {
  try {
    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
    final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts =
      new TrustManager[] {
        new X509TrustManager() {
          @Override
          public void checkClientTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}

          @Override
          public void checkServerTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}

          @Override
          public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};
          }
        }
      };

    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    // Create a ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
    final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true);

  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

// Create SOAP Connection
SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

// Do SOAP Call
soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage, soapEndPointUri);
```