# How to call a web service

Tags: java, web-services

Using Eclipse, I created a web service client from a wsdl. Eclipse generated the Java Classes after the wizard. 
What I'd like to do is to call the web service manually in one of the Classes I created.

However, not sure if I'm initializing the web service class correctly. Please see below screenshot:

[image]

Found some guides over the internet and basically what they do is create an instance of the web service class (MyWS_Service in my case) and initialize it by calling another class (ending with "locator" - in my case, MyWS_ServiceLocator) which contains a method that returns a type same as your web service class...

E.g.:

```
MyWS_Service service = new MyWS_ServiceLocator().getMyWS_Service();
// service.ExecuteMyMethod1("some parameter");
```

As shown in the intellisense result, this kind of method doesn't exist in the locator class.

Comment: how a webservice should be called depends on the type of service. (vs REST v SOAP)

Comment: this is SOAP I believe.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940234/how-to-do-a-soap-web-service-call-from-java-class/15942217