# Intellij will not recognize antlr generated source code

Tags: intellij-idea, antlr4

I am having trouble getting Intellij to recognize the generated source code from antlr4.  Any reference to the generated code appears as errors, code completion doesn't work, etc.

I am using maven and the antlr4-maven-plugin to generate the code.
My code, referencing the generated code compiles and builds fine under maven.
The generated code is under /target/generated-sources/antlr4, which is what Intellij expects.

I have tried the usual fixes such as reimport maven projects, update folders, invalidate cache, etc.  None of it seems to work.

Anyone seen this before?
Is there a way to point to the generated sources directly within Intellij?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had what I think may have been a similar issue.  I am new to IntelliJ, so I am guessing to some extent.

Is the gen folder in your project brown (i.e. a resource) or blue (source code)?

I could not get my project to recognize generated code until I managed to get the gen folder registered as one containing source code.

Sorry to say you may need to fiddle with it - I cannot recall how I did it - but all was well after I changed this.

Comment: Yep, I have had that issue before.  Clicking all the normal buttons usually gets it working.  All the normal buttons being: Maven compile, reimport project, generate sources, invalidate caches, restart IDEA.

Answer (score 20):

#### The problem

`target/generated-sources/antlr4` is not automatically marked as source dir, instead its direct subdir `com.example` is. Intellij Idea fails to detect proper package for classes inside `target/generated-sources/antlr4/com.example`.

#### The cause

The source file `*.g4` is in `src/main/antlr4/com.example`, but it actually it should be `src/main/antlr4/com/example`. Note the `/`. You probably forgot to mark `src/main/antlr4` as source dir in Idea, and when you thought you are creating package structure, you actually just created single dir called `com.example`.

#### The fix

Mark `src/main/antlr4` as source dir, create proper directory structure `src/main/antlr4/com/example`. Rebuild.

#### Alternative fix

Go to *Project Structure* - *Modules* - *Source Folders* and find the `target/generated-sources/antlr4/com.example` - click *Edit properties* and set *Package prefix* to `com.example`.

---

*Different but related problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35947085/2587343)*

Answer (score 6):

My issue was somewhat similar to [@spilymp's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34721042/6346531):

I was putting the `*.g4` files directly in `src/main/antlr4`:

```
.
├── src/
|   └── main/
|       ├── antlr/
|       |   ├── Main.g4
|       |   └── imported.g4
|       └── java/
|           └── com/
|               └── test/
|                   └── Test.java
```

which led to source being generated in `default` package. I changed the package structure to match that of java:

```
.
├── src/
|   └── main/
|       ├── antlr/
|       |   ├── com/
|       |   |   └── test/
|       |   |       └── Main.g4            
|       |   └── imports/
|       |       └── imported.g4
|       └── java/
|           └── com/
|               └── test/
|                   └── Test.java
```

(Note that imports need to go directly in `src/main/antlr4/imports`)

After this I just run the `antlr4` goal from the maven menu ([Module] > Plugins > antlr4 > antlr4:antlr4), which generated the sources in the default location (`target/generated-sources/antlr4`), where they were already marked with blue, generated-sources icon by Intellij, and `MainParser` can now be imported!

Answer (score 5):

Steps that worked for me:

1. Open **Maven Projects** in right tab
2. Right click on the module that contained my antlr code
3. Click **Generate Source and Update Folders**

Comment: Hey, that really worked ! Thanks. The generated-sources folder is marked as generated source root, and the rest of the target folder is still ignored. Perfect.

Comment: This is the one that solved the issue for me! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that my fiddling with preferences caused this issue.  If anyone else has this problem:

As v0rl0n mentioned, first make sure the gen folder is listed as a source.  Go to **Module Settings** -> **Modules** -> **Sources**.
Look to the right for the blue **Source Folders**.  Ensure your generated source folders are listed (they should have a **[generated]** flag on the row).

If your generated source directory is listed there, and they are still not being recognized, go to **Preferences** -> **File Types**.  Look in the **Ignore files and folders** field.  Make sure you don't have anything listed that will match for your generated sources directory.

In my case, I had added **target** to this list, which caused my problem, and was a real pain to find.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Intellij found my generated code in the `java` folder but not in a subfolder of `java`. I solved it by putting my grammar files (*.g4) into a package (com.test):

```
.
├── src/
|   └── main/
|       ├── antlr/
|       |   └── com.test/
|       |       └── Test.g4
|       └── java/
|           └── test/
|               └── Test.java
└── target/
    └── generated-sources/
        └── antlr/
            └── com.test/
                ├── TestBaseListener.java
                └── ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this issue is to Right-Click the `gen` directory and choose `Mark Directory as -> Sources Root`

[image]