# Intellij path rule to automatically recognize generated sources folder

Tags: intellij-idea, auto-generate, cxf-xjc-plugin

I would like to know if it is possible to set up a **rule** that marks a **generated sources folder** as **generated sources root** in **Intellij Idea automatically**.

Usually, Intellij detects the `target/generated-sources` directory as generated sources. My problem is that I also need it to automatically recognize the directory `target/generated` as generated sources, which Intellij never did in my case.
This is because of a maven plugin that I use for generating code from XSD schema:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <extensions>
                    <extension>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins:cxf-xjc-dv:${cxf.version}</extension>
                </extensions>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <xsdOptions>
                            <xsdOption>
                                <xsd>src/main/resources/schema.xsd</xsd>
                                <packagename>org.example.project.common.request</packagename>
                            </xsdOption>
                        </xsdOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

For some reason, this plugin generates code into the `target/generated` directory, and not into the `target/generates-sources`, of which I read that it is the convention and the default from many points of view.

I've tried searching on the web with similar keywords like in the title, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72787358) was the closest solution to what I wanted to achieve. And even this solution doesn't solve my problem because Intellij doesn't allow setting some path patterns; it only offers a few options that don't include `target/generated` directory.

Another solution suggests changing the target output, which I can't do in *every single project* I work on; that is not a solution either.

This is important to me because I work with many projects, and sometimes when my code builds with maven but doesn't compile with Intellij I forget to check whether I marked all the `generated` folders as sources, or I don't even know there are generated sources in the project.

Does someone know a way I can achieve that Intellij automatically detects source files in `target/generated` directory?

Comment: Try Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing | **Generated sources folders** option. There is a related request about `cxf-xjc-plugin` support: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-123702/maven-jaxb2-plugin-multiple-schema-wrong-generated-sources-root

Comment: @Andrey I've already tried it, I mean to set the path I'd like it to recognize, but there's no such option that would be good for me. I read about this setting in a SO post that I already linked in the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72787358
Anyways thanks for the youtrack link!