# How to turn off auto-generation of the GWT Asynchronous RPC interface in Maven

Tags: maven, gwt, code-generation, rpc, gwt-rpc

I'm working with a Java RPC service to communicate between the server and client side in my GWT application.  I don't want to remove the asynchronous interface from my version control, because it's required in order for the project to compile and run.

However, the Async interface gets generated automatically (along with the Messages class) in the target/generated-sources folder by a Maven plugin, and I get a duplicate class error when the application tries to run.

Does anybody know how to disable the auto-generation of the Asynchronous RPC interface?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by following this question:

[How to configure IntelliJ IDEA and/or Maven to automatically add directories with Java source code generated using jaxb2-maven-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644609/how-to-configure-intellij-idea-and-or-maven-to-automatically-add-directories-wit)

And then looking at the Maven GWT plugin at Mojo's website:

http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/async.html

... so it wasn't IDEA that was generating the code, but rather it was the GWT Maven plugin.  I disabled the auto-generation of the Async RPC and i18n Messages interfaces by commenting out the following two lines in my pom:

```
<goal>i18n</goal>
<goal>generateAsync</goal>
```

so that the plugin definition in pom.xml now looks like:

```
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>test</goal>
              <!--<goal>i18n</goal>-->
              <!--<goal>generateAsync</goal>-->
            </goals>
 . . .
```

And the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Actually commenting your POM is not the best way to do it.
I don't know about IDEA but with Eclipse "run configurations" you can specify the goals you want to execute. I guess IDEA must have [something similar (see link)](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html).

For instance I would have two distinct runners. One with the goals

```
gwt:generateAsync gwt:i18n gwt:css
```

and one with no specific goals, which will execute a full build.

```
clean install
```

In your case you would want to have

```
gwt:compile gwt:test
```

If you NEVER want to execute the gwt:generateAsync goal though, removing it might be considered as a good option.