# Where should I put IDL files and generated code in Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, protocol-buffers, thrift

I use standard Maven directory structure for my project

```
- src
  - main
    - java
    - resources
    - webapp
  - test
    - java
    - resources

- target
```

Now I want to use Thrift and gRPC but I don't know where should I put IDL files and where to put generated code? Is there any "standard" or "best practices" suggestion? Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you put the AIDL files in the 'exact' same package as you want your generated files to be (with respect to package), You put the AIDL files in your src/ tree and the 'generated' files will be in the 'generated' tree.

- src

  - main

    - java

      - org

        - whatever

          - project

            - services

              - aidl

                - POJO2.java
                - IRemoteService.aidl
                - IRemoteServiceCallback.aidl
                - POJO1.aidl

By doing this, the generated files will be in the 'org.whatever.project.services.aidl' package

Here is a good guide.
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Here is an example application: 
https://github.com/douglascraigschmidt/POSA-15/tree/502d9db2cbd90de3f4de0ed1bb74750004f47f06/ex/AcronymExpander/src/vandy/mooc/model/aidl

Comment: I think you right, it seems good to put IDL files in the same package with generated codes

Answer (score 1):

Generally sources generated by the build process go under the `target/generated-sources` directory.

If you're generating the sources from a third party tool that is not, or cannot be, integrated with your build process, then you should stash it in something like `generated/src/main` so that you know everything under it is generated.

In Intellij you can either use the maven default, or tell it explicitly where you have a generated source if you have it outside of the `target` folder and in something like `generated/src/main`

How to mark a directory in Intellij https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-content-roots.html#generated

Content roots explained https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/content-root.html

[How to configure IntelliJ IDEA and/or Maven to automatically add directories with Java source code generated using jaxb2-maven-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644609/how-to-configure-intellij-idea-and-or-maven-to-automatically-add-directories-wit)